# printing the text of the select element from composite instead of key

Tags: drupal, twig

I am trying to iterate and print the **text** of the select element selected by the user. The key of the composite is **item**.

```
{% for item in data.item %}
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ item.qty }} </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ item.book }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I know that **item.book** would only print the key. So how would I change it to print the text?

Comment: Can you show an example of the data.item object?

Comment: my_code: "This is the option text" here is how an option value and option text look like. I actually changed to different method by just making the value same as the text.

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72295986/print-the-table-based-on-the-selected-option-of-a-radio-element?noredirect=1#comment127730036_72295986 thank you