# Print the table based on the selected option of a radio element

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-webform

I have a radio element with three options (**Normal**, **Time Sensitive**, and **Hold For Pick-Up**). Every time an user clicks an option, an unique table element for the option (for user to fill information) will pop up automatically. Finally, I would like to print all the submitted data to PDF attachment.

As I write the twig code for it, I am stuck in the part where I want to print the table that belongs to the selected option

```
{# choose_your_shipping_option: radio's key  #}
{# Normal: option text #}
{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:choose_your_shipping_option]') == "Normal" %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Shipping Address:</th>
        <th>Acct #</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">[webform_submission:values:shipping_address]</td>
        <td>[webform_submission:values:id_num]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            [webform_submission:values:phone]
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% elseif webform_token('[webform_submission:values:choose_your_shipping_option]') == "Time Sensitive" %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Delivery Date</th>
        <td>[webform_submission:values:time_sensitive_01_delivery_date]</td>
        <th>Must Have Street Address (No PO Box)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Shipping Address:</th>
        <th>Acct #</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="text-align: center;">[webform_submission:values:shipping_address_2]</td>
        <td>[webform_submission:values:id_num]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            [webform_submission:values:phone_2]
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% elseif webform_token('[webform_submission:values:choose_your_shipping_option]') == "Hold For Pick-Up" %}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Will be picked up by</th>
        <th>Pick-up Date:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[webform_submission:values:pick_up_01_picked_up_by]</td>
        <td>[webform_submission:values:pick_up_01_pick_up_date]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Pick-up Location</th>
        <th>Pick-up Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[webform_submission:values:location]</td>
        <td>[webform_submission:values:time]</td>
    </tr>
</table>

{% endif %}
```

It would ruin the pdf template when I use **webform_token**. Is there a correct way to print only the one that's filled by the user?

Comment: You will either needs to use a form to post the selected options to a controller or use ajax to generate the PDF as you can't directly interact with twig as it's rendered serverside

Comment: On the code I attached, I think I am trying the first option you provided to print out the result in the PDF attachment. I'm just not able to print only the selected option and table filled out by the filler at this time.